# Problemas con consulta en gráfica Highcharts

Tags: php, highcharts

Estoy trabajando con highcharts, lo que deseo hacer es que los agrupe por fecha y los separe dependiento de la respuesta (SI o NO)

```
pregunta1            created_at
NO                   2019-02-24
SI                   2019-02-24
NO                   2019-05-24
NO                   2019-05-24
```

Que realice el conteo de cada mes y muestre el total en una barra de la respuesta Si y otra barra de la respuesta NO, aunque pertenezcan o no al mismo mes.

En esta consulta efectivamente me agrupa por fecha pero no respeta las respuestas, es decir; hay un SI y NO con la fecha 2019-02-24 pero no las separa por la respuesta SI o No (en el conteo encuentra dos registros con las mismas fechas).

[image: Error en gráfica agrupa por fecha pero no separa según el tipo de respuesta]

**Codigo grafica**

```html
<?php


     require_once("graphic_connection.php");

?>


<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  
  <title>Gráfica | Encuesta</title>
  
   
  <body>
     <img src="images/logos.png" alt="Logo" title="Logo"/>
  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
#container {
 height: 700px; 
 min-width: 510px; 
 max-width: 900px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            margin: 140,
            options3d: {
                enabled: true,
                alpha: 10,
                beta: 10,
                depth: 70
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Gráfica | Encuesta'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                depth: 25
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
   
   
   
  categories: 
  
  [
  
  
   <?php 
       $sql=mysql_query("SELECT pregunta1, COUNT(*) total
                      FROM encuesta where month(created_at)
                      
                      GROUP BY month(created_at) ORDER BY total DESC");
       while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       ?>
  
  
                ['<?php echo $res['pregunta1']   ?>'],
  
  
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  
  ]
   
   
   
   
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: '¿Nuestro ingeniero de soporte le ofreció una solución / respuesta de manera oportuna?',
            data:
   [
   
            <?php 
       $sql=mysql_query("SELECT pregunta1, COUNT(*) total FROM encuesta GROUP BY  month(created_at) ORDER BY total DESC");
       while ($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
       ?>
       
       
   
             [<?php echo $res['total']?> ],
   
   
    
    
           <?php
           }     
              ?>
   
   ]
        }]
    });
});
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>

<script src="Highcharts-4.1.5/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-4.1.5/js/highcharts-3d.js"></script>
<script src="Highcharts-4.1.5/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: la extensión `mysql` fue declarada obsoleta en `PHP 7`. En [la documentación oficial de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php) puedes consultar las extensiones permitidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendí bien lo que necesitas, tu error estaría en la consulta.

Tu consulta tal como la tienes

```
SELECT 
  pregunta1,
  COUNT(*) total 
FROM
  encuesta 
WHERE MONTH(created_at) 
GROUP BY MONTH(created_at) 
ORDER BY total DESC
```

Retorna:

```
pregunta1   total  
---------  --------
NO                2
NO                2
```

Pero la consulta debería ser

```
SELECT pregunta1, created_at FROM encuesta GROUP BY  pregunta1, created_at
```

Para que retorne:

```
pregunta1  created_at  
---------  ------------
NO         2019-02-24  
NO         2019-05-24  
SI         2019-02-24
```

Si lo quieres que cuente por día del mes la consulta sería

```
SELECT COUNT(DAY(created_at)) AS total , pregunta1, MONTHNAME(created_at) FROM encuesta GROUP BY  pregunta1, created_at

 total  pregunta1  MONTHNAME(created_at)  
------  ---------  -----------------------
     1  NO         February               
     2  NO         May                    
     1  SI         February
```

Aquí puedes ir jugando si necesitas que el mes te de por número `MONTH()` o por nombre del mes `MONTHNAME()` o cualquier tipo de extracción de la fecha.
¿Era eso lo que buscabas?

**Actualización**

En esta parte del código es donde se le coloca el campo y este a su vez en la gráfica aparecerá en la parte de abajo (coloque el MONTHNAME(created_at) y solo me aparece el mes y necesito que aparezca el mes junto con la respuesta de la pregunta, Ejemplo "ABRIL-NO", "ABRIL-SI")

[image: Grafica, solo aparece el mes]

Comment: Hola @Eduardo Munizaga, gracias por responder, la consulta que me hiciste favor de proporcionarme me devolvía justamente lo que comentaste que retornaría, pero le hice una modificación para que si fueran del mismo mes se sumaran en la variable total ejemplo NO 2019-02-28, NO 2019-02-28 = pregunta1-->NO   created_at-->2, pero el problema aun persiste ya que hace el COUNT con las fechas exactas y-m-d, si el día no es el mismo que las otras fechas no lo agrupa al mismo mes perteneciente.

Comment: Esta es la sentencia que realice------>   SELECT pregunta1, COUNT(*) total  FROM encuesta GROUP BY pregunta1, created_at

Comment: Exacto, si quieres desagregarlo por el día,  haces el count solo por el día COUNT(DAY(created_at)), lo voy a editar para que quede claro

Comment: la sentencia que me hiciste favor de proporcionarme hacia el COUNT si las fechas coincidan en Y-M-D, la modifique para que si fueran del mismo mes sin importar el día la agrupara.

Comment: Asi quedo la sentencia: SELECT COUNT(created_at) AS total , pregunta1, MONTHNAME(created_at) FROM encuesta GROUP BY  pregunta1, MONTHNAME(created_at) order by MONTHNAME(created_at) DESC

Comment: Solo tengo un nuevo problema en mi gráfica ya me asocia perfectamente, pero en las barras le coloque la descripción del mes para que lo mostrara pero quiero ver la posibilidad de que muestre mes y día es decir "ABRIL-SI" o "ABRIL-NO", agrego una imagen de como esta hasta el día de hoy las gráficas.

Comment: es en esta linea donde me obtiene el nombre de  las barras en la gráfica  ['<?php echo $res['MONTHNAME(created_at)']   ?>'],    Modifico el código como lo tengo hasta hoy.